# Read value of an evaluation returning an array from PHP-JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, copernica-php-js

I've recently started using this [PHP-JS](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-JS) library.
It's basically a php wrapper over Google's V8 javascript engine.

The main reason of using it is that it can run isolated javascript code.
And return the outcome.

It's no problem for `int` and `string` values. Those are returned as-is.

But I found myself creating an array and i need to return it.
I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type JS\Object as array

I'm doing this simple script:

```
<?php
$context = new JS\Context();
$script = "var arr = ". json_encode([2,3]).";x = arr.length";
var_dump($context->evaluate($script)); 
// int(2) - which is correct
```

But if I want to get the `arr` returned:

```
<?php
$script = "var arr = ". json_encode([2,3])."; arr;";
var_dump($context->evaluate($script));
// class JS\Object#1 (0) {}
```

*Note: `evaluate($stuff)` returns the last variable in the script.*

**Is there any nice way of returning that value?**

---

Update: After some digging, I've found a way to access data. What it does is encapsulate the array into a `stdClass` object:

```
$result = $context->evaluate($script);
echo $result->{0}; // outputs 2 
// also works for ->{1}
```

But it's still way too ugly to use in real-life

Comment: Have you tried casting to array? `print_r((array) $result);`

Comment: Yep, tried that. It gives: `array(0) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to extract `array` results of the evaluation:

```
$script = "var arr = ". json_encode([2,3]).";x = JSON.stringify(arr);";
```

At this point, `x` is a string:

```
var_dump($context->evaluate($script)); // string(5) "[2,3]"
```

Now all I needed to do is 'reverse' the `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var_dump(json_decode($context->evaluate($script),true));
// array(2) {
//   [0] => int(2)
//   [1] => int(3)
// }
```

---

**Update**

---

Arrays returned as `JS\Object` **are** iterable. So this is valid:

```
$script = "var arr = ". json_encode([2,3]).";arr";
foreach($obj as $key=>$val){
    print_r($key);echo " => ";print_r($val);echo "\n";
}
// output
// 0 => 2
// 1 => 3
```

It's not that nice when the return array is nested:

```
$script = "var arr = ". json_encode([2,3,[1,4]]).";arr";
$obj = $c->evaluate($script);
foreach($obj as $key=>$val){
    print_r($key);echo " => ";print_r($val);echo "\n";
}
// output
// 0 => 2
// 1 => 3
// 2 => JS\Object Object() <- this needs looping too
```

For the second example a recursive method is required to parse all levels.

So I'm sticking with the `JSON.stringify` and `json_decode($r, true)`;